# Docker - host.docker.internal" (192.168.65.2) refused to connect

Tags: postgresql, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to connect my PostgreSql database within Symfony and Docker and getting an error:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
db:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-12}-alpine
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-my_db}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-root}
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-root}
    volumes:
        - $PWD/postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    profiles:
        - db-in-docker
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    networks:
        - symfony
```

And **.env.dev.local**

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root:root@host.docker.internal:5432/my_db?serverVersion=12&charset=utf8"
```

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
>
> ```
>     Is the server running on host "host.docker.internal" (192.168.65.2) and accepting  
>     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

I evan edited my /etc/hosts file to connect this host to `127.0.0.1`

As this is Postgres database that is running on my Docker host, I am using the host.docker.internal, which maps to the host IP on Mac or WindowsUsing 127.0.0.1 or localhost will cause the code to try to connect to the same container running the code, which does not have a database running.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If Symfony is also running in docker, you can try to define ENV directly in docker-compose.yml and pass postgres "service" name/alias (docker will resolve this name)

sth like this (in symfony service definition)

```
 environment:
      - DATABASE_URL="postgresql://root:root@db/my_db?serverVersion=12&charset=utf8"
```

where "db" is your service name for postgres

I had similar issue and for me this alias helped.